# Drupal 8 how to show entity reference field in views exposed filter as select list?

Tags: 8, views

I have content types as Leaves and Branch. and I have an Branch ER field in Leaves.
How to show Branch as **select list** in views exposed filter Drupal 8?

I really need a solution asap.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the [Views Entity Reference Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/verf) module? The module is also capable of showing the values of the referenced entities in a filter instead of the IDs.

Answer (score 1):

I came across same situation long before. I did not remember exactly.

Check this link https://www.drupal.org/node/2429699

[image]

Comment: Yes I have seen that link. But non of the patches work. any other solution??

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is [entityreference_filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference_filter) module. it' working on drupal 8 and 9

> This module provides the views filter for entity ID or entity reference fields:
>
> node ID user ID taxonomy term ID term reference field (Drupal core)
> entity reference field (Entity reference module) Exposed filter
> functionality Taxonomy term filtering: Imagine the following case -
> you have taxonomy terms in exposed filter widget (drop down select
> list). But for some reason you want to show just several terms, not
> all the dictionary. With this module, you can do this by creating a
> separate view which generates the desired list of terms.
>
> The similar functionality is available for other type of fields - you
> create a separate view (or a new display of the same view) which
> returns the list of items to show in drop down select list of the
> exposed filter.